# What caused this drop?

Tags: stocks

https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS738US738&q=RMSLD&oq=RMSLD

Just looking over some stocks and saw this one.

Trying to find out why the stock dropped so much, I do not see any lawsuits or any activity on google at all.

Why or how would this stock drop over $33 in less than 10 days?

I know asking about specific stocks is usually opinion based however this one is interesting as there really is not news about the company except for their new patent which I would think would be a really good thing.

http://www.marketwired.com/press-release/remsleep-holdings-inc-announces-deltawave-its-patent-application-a-new-revolutionary-otc-pink-rmsld-2227356.htm

Comment: Bad news, the direction the wind blew, global warming?  The value of a security can move for any reason, and the severity of the movement is not predictable.  This particular movement seems to be a 20 for 1 reverse split: https://marketexclusive.com/remsleep-holdings-inc-otcmktsrmsl-files-an-8-k-amendments-to-articles-of-incorporation-or-bylaws-change-in-fiscal-year-2/2017/06/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a stock holder profit from a reverse-stock split?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/76788/does-a-stock-holder-profit-from-a-reverse-stock-split)

Comment: @quid That looks likes an answer

Comment: This is a good question. Asking about an anomaly in a stock chart is something that should be (and is) on topic here. It is not primarily opinion based and is not asking us to predict the future.

Comment: And it is okay to ask about specific stocks, as long as you are not asking for opinions or buy/sell advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you found this because of a stock screener.  This company went through a 1:20 reverse split on June 30, so every 20 shares outstanding became a single share.  Where before you had 20 shares worth $100 you now have 1 share worth $100, the value of the company doesn't change because of a split.  This company was never trading for $30+ per share.  Reverse splits are typical of a floundering company trading on an exchange that has a minimum share price requirement.  While reverse splits don't change the value of the company, just the number of shares outstanding and the price per share, no healthy company performs a reverse split.  Reverse splits are generally a massive signal to jump ship...

The company seems to be trading for $1 right now, why the value fell from a pre-split $1.65 ($33/20) to $1 is anyone's guess; how the company ever got to $1.65 is also anyone's guess. But looking at the most recent [10-Q](https://www.otcmarkets.com/edgar/GetFilingHtml?FilingID=12078124) there are numerous causes for concern:

---

**Note 2. Capital Stock**

On March 6, 2017, the Company issued as compensation for services provided a total of 650,000 common shares with a fair value of $390,000 to a third party. The fair value of the shares was based on the price quoted on the OTC pink sheets on the grant date.

*this indicates a share price of $0.60 ($390,000/650,000) as of 3/6/2017, just to reinforce that the google price chart doesn't show the true past but a past adjusted for the split*

---

**Results of Operations**

The three months ended March 31, 2017 compared to the three months ended March 31, 2016

For the three months ended March 31, 2017 compared to the three months ended March 31, 2016, total revenues were $0 and $0, respectively, and net losses from operations were $414,663 and $26,260, respectively. The net losses were attributable to costs attributable to operating as a public company, **in particular, common stock with a valuation of $390,000 that was issued to an investor relations firm in the first quarter of 2017**.

---

**Going Concern**

As of March 31, 2017, there is substantial doubt regarding our ability to continue as a going concern as we have not generated sufficient cash flow to fund our proposed business.

We have suffered recurring losses from operations since our inception. **In addition, we have yet to generate an internal cash flow from our business operations or successfully raised the financing required to develop our proposed business.** As a result of these and other factors, our independent auditor has expressed substantial doubt about our ability to continue as a going concern.

---

**Liquidity and Capital Resources**

We had no cash as of the date of March 31, 2017.

---

Additionally, since there is no balance sheet in the last [10-Q](https://www.otcmarkets.com/edgar/GetFilingHtml?FilingID=12078124) (another bad sign), the last annual report [10-K](https://www.otcmarkets.com/edgar/GetFilingHtml?FilingID=11998780) has this balance sheet:

```
ASSETS                                            2016

CURRENT ASSETS:     
Cash in Bank                                     $   -
Prepaid Expenses                                     -
Total Current Assets                                 -

PROPERTY AND EQUIPMENT - net                    12,845

TOTAL ASSETS                                  $ 12,845


LIABILITIES AND STOCKHOLDERS' EQUITY (DEFICIT)      

CURRENT LIABILITIES     
Accounts payable                            $  226,398
Due to shareholder                              85,287

TOTAL CURRENT LIABILITIES                      311,685
```

So the company:

- has zero cash,
- some bit of equipment worth $13k
- owes $311k (this is before the $390k expense above that was paid in stock)

  - that $390k payment is 30x the company's total assets....
- has never successfully raised funding to develop the proposed business
- and the cherry on top:

  - doesn't think it can continue as a going concern

So why did the stock value plummet? It's anyones' guess but there is no shortage of ways to justify it.

In fact, it's reasonable to ask how is this company still worth $3mm ($1 * 3mm shares outstanding)...

Comment: Broken 10-K and 10-Q links.

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully understand the transactions involved, but it appears that there was a reverse stock split (20:1) and some legal status change as well on June 29th. This seems to be the cause for the change in valuation of the stock as the dates match the drop.

https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RMSLD/filings

Comment: The link is broken.